# flickering my jframe even i used doubleBuffer

Tags: java, swing, jframe

when I call a repaint method its flickering, I was searching on the internet about doubleBuffered but its stil flickering all of objects on the same time,

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;


public class GuiGame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
  
    private final Flower flower;
    private final ArrayList<MyObjects> objekty;

    private Image dbImage;
    private Graphics dbGraphics;


    public GuiGame() {
        this.setFocusable(true);
        Timer timer = new Timer(40, this);
        timer.start();
        this.setVisible(true);
/*

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
         this.dbImage = this.createImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        this.dbGraphics = this.dbImage.getGraphics();
        this.paintComponents(g);
        g.drawImage(this.dbImage, 0 ,0, this);
    }

*/
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
  //when i use doubleBuffering this method was called paintComponents
       
        g.drawImage(background.getImage(), 0, 0, this);
        g.drawImage(flower.getImage(), flower.getPozX(), flower.getPozY(), this);
        String skore = "Score: " + player.getScore() ;
        g.drawString(skore, 20, 50);
        this.paintObjects(g);
    }

    public void paintObjects(Graphics g) {
        if (this.objekty != null) {
            for (objekty o : this.objekty) {
                o.move();
                g.drawImage(o.getImage(), o.getPozX(), o.getPozY(), this);
            }
        }
    }
```

when I used doubleBuffering I tried to slow down a timer e.g. to 1000, it was blank page for most of the time and my objects was there only for moment.

when I do not used it, only last objects which i draw were flickering.
how can I avoid?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you start by taking a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).

Swing components, when used correctly, are double buffered by default.

Painting is very complex, there's a lot of work that goes into a paint pass.  When you override a "paint" method, you either need to honour the existing workflow (ie, call the `super.paintXxx` method) or be prepared to take over the full responsibility of the method. Your code has circumvented whole sections of the paint workflow, this is never a good idea.

It's not generally recommend that you extend from top level containers like `JFrame`, you're not adding any new functionality and they are generally complex components to start with.  `JFrame` for example, is actually a composite component, that is, it has a number of child components added to it that form it's core functionality

[image]

By overriding `paint` (of `JFrame`), you start competing with these components, and because a child component can be painted without the parent been involved, this can lead to any number of issues.

Instead, start with a `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method, this guarantees that you will be operating in a double buffered workflow.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.add(new MainPane());
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class MainPane extends JPanel {

        private int xDelta = 1;
        private int xPos = 0;
        private BufferedImage ufo;

        public MainPane() throws IOException {
            ufo = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/ufo.png"));

            Timer timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    xPos += xDelta;
                    if (xPos + ufo.getWidth() > getWidth()) {
                        xPos = getWidth() - ufo.getWidth();
                        xDelta *= -1;
                    } else if (xPos < 0) {
                        xPos = 0;
                        xDelta *= -1;
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            paintUFO(g2d);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        protected void paintUFO(Graphics2D g2d) {
            int y = (getHeight() - ufo.getHeight()) / 2;
            g2d.drawImage(ufo, xPos, y, this);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: *"Swing components, when used correctly, are double buffered by default."* But with the notable exception of classes like `JFrame`..

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yeah, which is why you need to use them "correctly" :P